relationship between boundedness, and uniform convergence for functional serise.
If a functional series is not bounded on I, and converges to some function f, that doesn't imply that f_n is not uniformally converges, yet i don't know where
my teacher have deduced this result, check the link below.
Here is the image
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/8rtWM2TK.png

If the convergence is uniform, then $|S(x)|\le |S_m(x)-S(x)|+|S_m(x)|\le 1+(m+1)$ if $m$ is chosen large enough (independent of $x$).  So $S$ will be bounded in that case.
